# dynamic created content bind keyup change javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, bind

Well I've been reading on how to do this, but no success so far.

At first I thought the problem was another, then I read about dynamic created content and that you have to bind it to something already in web.

I've tried using this, but im sure I'm not using it correctly:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'email', function () {
  //the code from below here.
});
```

how do I bind this?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding all the elements to the query selector or just use the same class for both.

```
$(".email1, .email").on("keyup change", function() {});
```

Comment: How do u add add the elements? I'm new in Javascript.